# PostgreSQL and Pyramid: ProgrammingError: relation "records" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, pyramid

I have to test an existing pyramid application.

I have to set up a local PostgreSQL server with a database with some records.

Then I have to set up a python virtual environment and start web-server for the existing pyramid application.

The application is up and running in localhost but when I try to add a record in the connected(!) db through the web page I receive errors. I suppose that its not connected to the db.

Because I am new with Pyramid and PostgreSQL is there any tutorial which I can follow?

The steps I followed were:

Setup the local PostgreSQL server.

Setup the python virtual environment and start the web-server for the pyramid application (in a different terminal).

ERRORS:
pserve development.ini
Starting server in PID 13630.
serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080

```
2015-11-22 19:49:10,965 ERROR [waitress][waitress] Exception when serving /get_records
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.10-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 336, in service
    task.service()
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.10-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 169, in service
    self.execute()
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.10-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 388, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 223, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 198, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 20, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.12-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 99, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.12-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 80, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 145, in handle_request
    view_name
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/view.py", line 541, in _call_view
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 351, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 505, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/wsyscore/wsyscore/views.py", line 44, in get_records
    records = base.database.get_records()
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/wsyscore/wsyscore/Database.py", line 107, in get_records
    cursor.execute(sql_sentense, ids)
ProgrammingError: relation "records" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from records;
                      ^

2015-11-22 19:49:12,783 ERROR [waitress][waitress] Exception when serving /record/create_new_record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.10-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 336, in service
    task.service()
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.10-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 169, in service
    self.execute()
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.10-py2.7.egg/waitress/task.py", line 388, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(env, start_response)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 223, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 198, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 20, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.12-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 99, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.12-py2.7.egg/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 80, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 145, in handle_request
    view_name
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/view.py", line 541, in _call_view
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 351, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.6b2-py2.7.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 505, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/wsyscore/wsyscore/views.py", line 141, in create_new_record
    record_id = base.database.init_record(main_template)
  File "/home/atroul/pyramid_sites/wsyscore/wsyscore/Database.py", line 62, in init_record
    cursor.execute(sql_sentense, [psycopg2.extras.Json(initial_record['main'])])
ProgrammingError: relation "records" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO records (seq, main) VALUES (0, '{"first_names": ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to query SQL table `records` which does not exist.

Either

- Create this table in your database using PostgreSQL clients (command line client)
- If you think the table should already exist then fix your SQL query for spelling and refer to correct tables

[pgcli](http://pgcli.com/) - better command line interface for PostgreSQL